# Use variables from a custom name script file provided by user

Tags: python-3.x, user-input

I'm currently building an user friendly program in Python. Currently, the user is able to modify the input values provided in an init script that we can call `init.py`. At this moment the user can open in Spyder, the `main.py` and run/execute the whole process or just typing the classical command:

`python3 main.py`

The `main.py` file import all the variables needed from the `init.py` and run normally. What I would like to do now is to add a feature which allows the user to change the name of the `init.py` file. For example to be able to build `initcustom.py`.
And use the following command :

`python3 main.py initcustom.py`

How can I be able to import variables in `main.py` from a script which can change name (that should be provided by the user in the command line)?

And in the case where nothing is specified we keep the classical `init.py`

What such feature will induce as changes in the case where someone just want to do `F5` using Spyder without precising input names?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do something with `exec`

```
import sys
exec(‘import’+’sys.argv[2]’)
```